# JQueryMobile and PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to develop a register a login app for android using
 JQueryMobile and Phonegap. The problem when the username and password
 is verified by sever, i don't know how to redirect the user to his
 personal home page, and it works fine when i alert the user that
 username & password is correct.
2)In Phonegap , is it necessary
 to put all the code in just one www/index.html file? cant we create
 another html file to link it up? will it still work as a android app?
thanks!

Comment: You can have several html pages inside your application, you can open your html page using window.open("http://www.aaabbb.com"); or get knowledge of InAppBrowser plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple pages (html).

Only have scripts and other details in the index.html page with a structure like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />    

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<div id="pageIndex" data-role="page" class="content" data-theme='b'>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And you can then have individual pages (html) like below in some html folder:

```
<div id="pageLogin" data-role="page" class="content" data-theme='b'>

<div  data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme='b'>
<h1>Header - Login Page</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
Content for Login Page

</div>
</div>
```

Index.html will by default load and then on wards you can use jquery mobile change page in the respective pageshow events.

```
 $(document).on("pageshow", "#pageIndex", function () { 
    //directly navigate to the login page
    $.mobile.changePage("html/pageLogin.html");
 });

 $(document).on("pageshow", "#pageLogin", function () { 
    //directly navigate to the home page on validation of user in login buttion click event
    $.mobile.changePage("html/pageHome.html");
 });
```